# Align Body from Header of Table after inserting values on table body

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, css-tables

**Problem :**

- The contents of the table body are not aligned with the header of each column of the table.

**Code :**

```js
var test_insert1 = '<tr>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-9">762261</td>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-7">1.16176</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-8">1.1618</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-1">2018-08-08</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-2">03:32</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-3">This is a test long value</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-4">1.00</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-5">Up</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-6">0.80</td>' +
  '</tr>'+
  '<tr>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-9">456985</td>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-7">1.65476</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-8">1984218</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-1">2018-08-08</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-2">03:32</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-3">This is a test value</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-4">10000</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-5">Up</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-6">1.00</td>' +
  '</tr>';

$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#new_table_test_body').html(test_insert1);
});
```

```css
#new_table_test {
  width: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* color:white; */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#new_table_test tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

#new_table_test tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

#new_table_test thead tr {
  display: block;
}

#new_table_test thead {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

#new_table_test th,
#new_table_test td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="new_table_test">
  <thead id="new_table_test_header">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header Two</th>
      <th>Head Three</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Heads 6</th>
      <th>Header seven</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
      <th>Header Nine</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="new_table_test_body"></tbody>
</table>

<button id="add"> Add Details </button>
```

-- EDIT --

Additional:

**Conditions:**

- Scrolling of table body is possible
- Header is not affected by scrolling (fixed)
- Width should auto adjust based on content

Here is also an updated fiddle for my concern: http://jsfiddle.net/9sjyvb5w/50

Comment: Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/9sjyvb5w/35/
Done a lot of modifications, might be helpful.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar you might want to post an answer and elaborate your changes, this might be useful for me and also for others

Comment: Okay , i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
#new_table_test {
  width: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

To this :

```
#new_table_test {
  width: 1000px;
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

Also you should remove `display: block;` from `#new_table_test tbody` and `#new_table_test thead tr`.

There is more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) about `table-layout` Property.

[jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/9sjyvb5w/22/)

[jsfiddle with scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/9sjyvb5w/57/)

[jsfiddle with fixed header](http://jsfiddle.net/uhv31kmt/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am looking for a fix that would auto adjust the width based on the length of the content making each columns not having same width and would display the content in a single line. I would not want to make it in a fixed 10%

Comment: Your solution is brilliant however this solution is not working properly on what I expect.
The reason I have the display: block on the table body is for it to be able to have a scroll and not fully display the content of the body. like this http://jsfiddle.net/9sjyvb5w/50/. Would you be able to add additional fix for this ?

Comment: you can wrap your table in a `div` and set `height` and `overflow: auto` for that. I updated my answer and did it on my previous example.

Comment: I understand. But doing that will make the header follow the scroll and is not fixed. Is there additional adjustments for this ?

Comment: use this jquery plugin : https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Comment: It finally worked! See: http://jsfiddle.net/uhv31kmt/6/
Thank you so much!

Comment: @shifu My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Although @bahman answer looks good, but in the meanwhile i tried something different approach with `flex property`.

**Approach :**
Before data load, i have made visible the `<thead>`, but on click of buton i have hidden the `<thead>` and only `<tbody>` is visible with the first row containing the header-values, and styled the first row accordingly to match the header.

**Problem with approach :**
 More manipulations required, more of a complex as requires to add first row as header.

```js
var test_insert1 = 
'<tr>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-9">Header 1</td>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-7">Header Two</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-8">Head Three</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-1">H4</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-2">Header 5</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-3">Header 6</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-6">Head 45</td>' +
  '</tr>'+'<tr>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-9">762261</td>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-7">1.16176</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-8">1.1618</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-1">2018-08-08</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-2">03:32</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-3">This is a test long value</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-6">0.80</td>' +
  '</tr>'+
  '<tr>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-9">456985</td>' +
  '<td  class="td-trad-7">1.65476</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-8">1984218</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-1">2018-08-08</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-2">03:32</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-3">This is a test value</td>' +
  '<td class="td-trad-6">1.00</td>' +
  '</tr>';

$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#new_table_test_body').html(test_insert1);
  $('#new_table_test_header').hide();
});
```

```css
#new_table_test {
  width: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* color:white; */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#new_table_test_header,
#new_table_test_body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#new_table_test_body > tr:first-child {
background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#new_table_test tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

#new_table_test tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  
}

#new_table_test thead tr {
  display: block;
}

#new_table_test thead {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

#new_table_test th,
#new_table_test td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="new_table_test">
  <thead id="new_table_test_header">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header Two</th>
      <th>Head Three</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Heads 6</th>
      <th>Head 45</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="new_table_test_body"></tbody>
</table>

<button id="add"> Add Details </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your table css (#new_table_test):

```
#new_table_test{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; //prevents word wrapping
    ....
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLevx0tn/

Comment: sorry, my bad. but the code to avoid wrapping is "white-space: nowrap". I wanted to help you with no-wrap. :) Nevermind